# Get input prefix as int in Python

Tags: python, string, parsing

In C++, if I have a string

```
string s = "123abc";
```

and I wanted to get the `123` part as an int, I'd do

```
istringstream ss(s);
s >> myint;
```

leaving the `abc` part (if needed). How should this be done in Python?

Comment: Another way: `''.join(itertools.takewhile(str.isdigit, s))`

Comment: @200OK - lol.  I had the same idea. :)

Comment: But, I think that the C++ example would work for negative numbers as well -- No?

Comment: @mgilson - If the OP needs that functionality, the solution you gave in the comments will work with a minor adaption: `int(re.match(r'^-?\d+', s).group())`

Comment: yep, that's what I was thinking.  In that case, I think that regex outshines the alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) and some [string methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods):

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> s = '123abc'
>>> int(''.join(takewhile(str.isdigit, s)))
123
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best that I can come up with:

### Regex

Using match position

```
import re

s = '123abc'
match = re.match('^[0-9]+', s)
i = int(s[:match.end(0)])
```

0-width split ([doesn't work](http://bugs.python.org/issue3262))

```
import re

s = '123abc'
i, rest = re.split('(?<=[0-9])(?=[^0-9])', s, maxsplit=1)
i = int(i)
```

### str

Simple

```
for j, c in enumerate(s):
    if not c.isdigit():
        break

i = int(s[:j])
```

Comment: seems like match groups would be easier:  `int(re.match(r'^(\d+)', s).group(0))`.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?:

```
>>> import re
>>> test = re.compile("^-?([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]+)")
>>> result = test.match("123abc")
>>> result.group(0)
'123abc'
>>> int(result.group(1))
123
>>> result.group(2)
'abc'
```

## update:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = '123abc'
>>> b = '-123abc'
>>> c = '123 abc'
>>> d = '-123      ABC'
>>> test = re.compile("(^-?[0-9]+)( +)?([a-zA-Z]+)")
>>> e = [a,b,c,d]
>>> [int(test.match(x).group(1)) for x in e]
[123, -123, 123, -123]
>>> [test.match(x).group(2) for x in e]
[None, None, ' ', ' ']
>>> [test.match(x).group(3) for x in e]
['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'ABC']
```

Also:

```
>>> [test.match(x).group(0,1,2,3) for x in e]
[('123abc', '123', None, 'abc'), ('-123abc', '-123', None, 'abc'), ('123 abc', '123', ' ', 'abc'), ('-123 ABC', '-123', ' ', 'ABC')]
>>> [test.match(x).group(0,1,2,3) for x in e][0]
('123abc', '123', None, 'abc')
>>> int([test.match(x).group(0,1,2,3) for x in e][0][1])
123
>>> int([test.match(x).group(0,1,2,3) for x in e][2][1])
123
>>> int([test.match(x).group(0,1,2,3) for x in e][3][1])
-123
>>> [test.match(x).group(0,1,2,3) for x in e][3][2]
' '
>>> [test.match(x).group(0,1,2,3) for x in e][3][3]
'ABC'
```

Comment: Would fail on `123 abc`.

Comment: @leewangzhong I tried to update the answer to include several different possibilities. Are there any other formats? Or extraneous characters?

Comment: Well, it's not like I need it for something.

Comment: Oh, my issue with your solution was that you're trying to stop on specific characters. Hint: instead of trying to guess what comes after a number, you should be thinking about, "How can I tell that it's no longer part of a number?"

Answer (score 0):

`int("123abc".strip(string.letters))`

Similar to the `itertools.takewhile` answer, but defines what is to be removed. This snippet would fail on the '123 abc' suggestion, for example. Also, it does not care where the letters to be removed are. I'd prefer the `takewhile` approach, since its more robust to input changes.